# Encontrar elemento sem tag ID e Name

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, excel-vba

Caros,

Preciso localizar o elemento que não contem id e nem name no HTML.

Abaixo esta o HTML exemplo

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" data-ng-if="novo2()" data-ng-click="novo()" clickonce="">
                Criar Protocolo
   </button>
```

Comment: Tente encontrar pela classe `class="btn btn-primary ng-scope"` ou pelo tipo `type="button"` e se o Valor for igual a `Criar Protocolo`

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar tambem para encontrar o elemento pelo nome da class css

```
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
```

Caso vc esteja usando jQuery fica ainda mais facil e rápido, pois vc tem como colocar criterio na busca do elemento.

> var elm = $('button[class*="btn"]')

O codigo diz: buscar todo elemento button que contenha uma class "btn";

Se quiser aprender mais sobre Jquery Selector [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Tente localizar pelo Xpath do elemento. Geralmente esse é o modo mais fácil quando não se tem um identificador único .

Answer (score 0):

Bem, não entendo porque não criar um id ou um name, mas para todo caso:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

Com isso você obterá uma lista com todos os "<"button">" do programa, assim você pode encontrar por indexação:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
```